# .Net Add-In Framework using log4net in add-in

Tags: .net, log4net, add-in

I am creating an application that uses add-ins with the .Net Add-Ins Framework.  I want to track what goes on inside the add-in using log4net, but I cannot get the logged data to write to the output file.  I am using log4net successfully with the host.

In my add-in's assemblyinfo.cs I've added this line of code:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

This should tell log4net to get the configuration from the .config file.

My app.config for the add-in looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
             initializeData="UpdateModuleLog.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern 
            value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level  value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

The add-in's app.config gets moved to the pipeline as expected.

In my addin, I have the following code to instantiate log4net:

```
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
        (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Finally, I call log4net in my code like this:

```
        log.InfoFormat("Starting Update Module Version 1.0.0 for Internationalization Database.");
```

The problem is that UpdateModuleLog.log is never created.  I would expect it to be created either in the host application's bin folder, or the add-ins folder in the pipeline, but it doesn't exist in either place.  I'm using the TraceAppender because I want to log anything written to Debug or Trace to the same file, but if this requires writing to a separate file then so be it.

Also, the log file for the host process does NOT reflect any of the logging done from the Add-Ins.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  My app.config was missing this section of code:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
      type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, 
            log4net"/>
  </configSections>
```